# Replace all spaces and symbols(!#.,;&()) by dash(-) in all file names of a folder with batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm dealing with a lot of files, mostly `.jpg`, that need to be batch renamed for ftp use (5k+ per day). Need a batch file to convert filenames to lowercase and replace all spaces and symbols(`!#.,;&()`) with dashes(`-`), as an example:

```
POS!99/6 09.JPG -> pos-99-6-09.jpg
75@0hu dfs*1010.jpg -> 75-0hudfs-1010.jpg
```

Please, help!
I just tried to set files in lowercase and dont know how to do the rest:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%%f" "%%f")
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_." %%F in ('dir /b "*_*.*"') do ren "%%F_%%G.%%H" "%%F.%%H"
endlocal
del *.bat
```

Comment: Please verify that what appears in the code box in your now formatted question is what you see in your own, (and [Edit] it if not). Also it is not possible for the characters `?` or `:` to be used in Windows filenames, so please do not just add random characters to your question, [Edit] it to include only those you are really encountering.

Comment: As you did not [Edit] your code, I have to tell you that there is a need to remove the last visible character from the end of lines one through five, (as they are not valid).

Comment: Equally, `*` and `/` are invalid in filenames. Are you prepared to use a 3rd-party utility like `sed` to assist in the solution?

Comment: * and / are deleted from the list. No, just wanted to do it with .bat, if it possible

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html could help if you insist upon `.bat` solution…

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick using VBScript Replace RegEx into a batch file :

***Note :*** The pattern to validate a filename is `[\\\/:*?\x22<>|]`, and I added in this class to yours for your request `!#.,;&()@`

---

```bat
@echo off
Color 0A & Title How to verify if variable contains valid filename in Windows Batch
echo(
Echo Enter filename for this project
set /p "my_filename="
echo(
echo Before Removing the special char the filename is like this : "%my_filename%"
pause
echo(
Call :Remove_Special_Char "%my_filename%" NewFileName
echo After Removing the special char the filename becomes like this : "%NewFileName%"
pause & exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Remove_Special_Char <String> <Variable to Set>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = wscript.Arguments(0^) 
    echo strPattern = "[\\\/:*?\x22<>|!#.,;&()@ ]"
    echo strReplace = "-"
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
@For /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" "%~1"') do ( Set "%2=%%i" )
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Or using Powershell to replace RegEx into a batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Color 0A & Title How to verify if variable contains valid filename in Windows Batch
echo(
Echo Enter filename for this project
set /p "my_filename="
echo(
echo Before Removing the special char the filename is like this : "%my_filename%"
pause
echo(
Call :Remove_Special_Char "%my_filename%" NewFileName
echo After Removing the special char the filename becomes like this : "%NewFileName%"
pause & exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Remove_Special_Char <String> <Variable to Set>
Set "psCommand='"%~1"' -replace '[\\\/:*?\x22<>|!#.,;&()@ ]','-'"
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`Powershell -C "%psCommand%"`) do (Set "%2=%%i")
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

***EDIT :***

```bat
@echo off
Color 0A & Title Rename
Set "MainFolder=E:\Batch\Stack\Test"
CD /D "%MainFolder%"

@for /f "Tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l /b /a-d') do (
    SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Call :Remove_Special_Char "%%~f" NewVar
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo( rename "%%~f" "!NewVar!"
    pause
    rename "%%~f" "!NewVar!"
)
EndLocal & pause & exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Remove_Special_Char <String> <Variable to Set>
Set "psCommand=""""%~1"""" -replace '[\\\/:*?\x22<>|!#.,;&()\x20@]','-'"
@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`Powershell -C "%psCommand%"`) do (Set "%2=%%i")
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Doesnt work with .bat, how should I run it? + I need to rename all files at once, not just one filename

Comment: @MaksymMerenkov Check my last edit code and tell me the results on your side